# Is there any documentation about Office365 SSO using python?

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, office365, single-sign-on

I'm currently trying to develop an application to use ms-graph API using python.
I'm trying to use SSO authentication but I cant find any resources or documentation related.
I found this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins
but it is only for javascript.

I wrote a script using Flask and another script using O365 python package.
It doesnt seem like its a Single sign on application that I try to achieve...

I'm looking for any documentation that could help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is not obvious how python is related. Office add-ins you mean are running in browser, so they are using javascript. Python (and Flask) is a server-side technology, but the office add-ins run client side (in the browser, not on the server)

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the Office web add-ins where you could also use SSO. But it seems you are developing a standalone application where Graph API is used. In that case you may find the [Configure SAML-based single sign-on for your application using the Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/application-saml-sso-configure-api) tutorial helpful.